# "Unsupported Get Request" - Facebook Realtime updates for Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

Everything is set up just fine. I can receive and log the data that facebook pushes to my callback server.

I'm monitoring the feed for updates, specifically posts. When I post as the page, I can get the post_id and call the graph api to get the details.

When I post as a user to the page I get this information:

```
{
   "object":"page",
   "entry":[
      {
         "id":"**[PAGE ID]**",
         "time":1385465393,
         "changes":[
            {
               "field":"feed",
               "value":{
                  "item":"post",
                  "verb":"add",
                  "post_id":**[INVALID POST ID]**,
                  "sender_id":**[USER WHO SENT POST]**
               }
            }
         ]
  }
   ]
}
```

Which is the typical output. Note that I have removed the identifiers and replaced them with placer holders.

When I extract the post_id and query it using the graph API it returns the following message:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

I have:

- Validated my page access token using the debugger (this has manage_pages permissions    associated with it and is permanent)
- Queried the graph API -> **[My Page ID]/feed** returns the posts I want to retrieve but their post id's are different to the ones I have been sent by Facebook.
- Created a fresh user account in case it was an issue with Facebook's spam detector (maybe my many tests post had triggered the spam filter?) but to no avail.
- Ensured that my page allows users of age 13+ and has no country restrictions
- Ensured app is not in sandbox mode
- Ensured there weren't any silly permission issues in the app configuration such as alcohol page or not having the age set to 13+

So I'm stumped.

Why is Facebook not sending me the correct post_id? Why is it sending me one that is invalid? And how do I get around this considering my app is central to the use of real time updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be a facebook-related issue. I basically had to modify my code to take into account that RTU sent you a differently formatted post ID depending on whether you were a page administrator or an average user.

If you're a page admin the format of the page ID will be **[PAGE ID]**_**[POST ID]**, but if you're an average user RTU will just send you the post ID without the page ID prefixed.

A little bit confusing... Not sure if a bug has been filed with Facebook just yet.

Comment: hi, can you give me some hint about how subscribe to a page/feed? I created the app, is configured to get Real Time Updates from "object:page" and "fields:feed", i added it to my page as a Tab, and still got nothing. The docs about this is very weak.

Comment: Yes, it's quite inconvenient how poorly documented some of the RTU documentation is. I believe it assumes prior knowledge for some aspects which make it difficult to get started if you haven't had much experience.

I haven't looked at this for a while. Have you tested your callback URL in the RTU configuration within facebook?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Strainy. My callback is ok. I'm receiving notifications for "user:likes", but i'm getting nothing for "page:feed" and even for "user:feed". Starting to wonder if the problem is with "feed".

Comment: Are you not receiving any object from RTU? How are you testing this?

Comment: Hi @Strainy. 

I'm not receiving nothing that should be coming from a "object:page". From Users i'm getting everything correctly, now including "user:feed" that wasn't working before (read_stream permission was missing). 

Could you tell me which permissions your app? 

Thx for your reply.

Comment: SOLVED Hello again @Strainy. Thank you for your patience. Finally i got my problem solved and now i can get "page:feed" working. I will just let the information on this comment in case another person stumble here with a similiar problem. I'm really pissed with Facebook Docs because i lost a huge time on a simple thing. There is 2 URLs to add and App to a Tab. Using this "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&next=YOURDOMAIN" IT WASN'T WORKING. But with this one "http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_ID&pages=1" IT WORKS  and now i'm receiving Real Time Updates from a page.

Comment: I have tried both url and still does not work me :( It is a bit annoying... I add subscriptions for my app with object:page, I have installed the app into the page with this two links... I have the permissions manage_pages... But I only get the user updates. Am I missing something?